# How to get the signed floating-point zero in C99?

Tags: c, floating-point, c99

How can we get the signed floating-point zero in C99?  Actually, I would like to checkout its bit pattern.

Comment: all floating-point types are *signed*. If you want *negative zero*, it's a different thing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By *signed floating-point zero*, I think you mean negative zero. If so, you can use `-0.0`.

Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void test(double val)
{
   unsigned char array[sizeof(double)];

   memcpy(array, &val, sizeof(double));
   for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(double); ++i )
   {
      printf("%02hhx", array[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
   double v1 = -0.0;
   double v2 = 0.0;

   test(v1);
   test(v2);
};
```

Output in my setup (64 bit Linux/gcc 4.8.4):

```
0000000000000080
0000000000000000
```

The C standard does not mandate that negative zero be supported. I can only find phrases like "*On implementations that represent a signed zero*".

If a compiler uses IEEE 754 representation for floating point numbers, they are required to support negative zero. From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_zero#Representations.

> In IEEE 754 binary floating point numbers, zero values are represented by the biased exponent and significand both being zero. Negative zero has the sign bit set to one. One may obtain negative zero as the result of certain computations, for instance as the result of arithmetic underflow on a negative number, or `−1.0*0.0`, or simply as `−0.0`

Comment: I don't doubt this worked on the c compiler you tested it on, but do you have a reference to the standard?

Comment: Nice. Beware that with `printf("%02x", array[i])`, because of default argument promotions, you are passing an `int` for an unsigned format. I have taken to using `%02hhx` recently, since I realized that everyone reasonable already takes it to mean “the argument is an `int` but it was promoted from `unsigned char`. See for instance Clang's warnings at https://github.com/TrustInSoft/tis-interpreter/issues/46

Answer (score 1):

you can use the C statement:

```
float zero = 0.0f;
```

all `float` is signed, that is part of the format of a `float` number

Answer (score 1):

```
int main(){

  float f = 0.0f;

  //observe as an array of bytes
  unsigned char *c = (unsigned char *)(&f);

  //for each byte in the float
  for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(float); ++i){

    //for each bit in the byte
    for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(char) * CHAR_BIT; ++j){

      //print 1 or 0 based on the bit value
      ((c[i] >> j) & 1) ? printf("1") : printf("0");

    }
  }
}
```

Take a look at [Float Toy](http://evanw.github.io/float-toy/).
It's a useful tool for visualizing IEEE floating-point format.